# How to get the path of selected image from gallery?

Tags: android, android-intent, image-gallery

I need to store the path of selected image from gallery. In the Toast i am getting the String 
   imageEncoded =null. I also have a List variable imageEncodedList which also gives 'null' in the Toast 
   when multiple images are selected. What i am doing wrong? i want to store the path of selected images in android. Also what i need to do for API level <18 for selecting images from gallery?

```
int SELECT_PICTURES=1;
String imageEncoded;
List<String> imagesEncodedList;
select_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURES);

        }
    });
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURES && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();
            if(data.getData()!=null){

                Uri mImageUri=data.getData();

                // Get the cursor
         Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(mImageUri, 
                                  filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"one "+imageEncoded,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                    ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                    ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                        ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                        Uri uri = item.getUri();
                        mArrayUri.add(uri);
                        // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        // Move to first row
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"two"+imageEncoded,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        imagesEncodedList.add(imageEncoded);
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't selected any Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add Permission in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**For getClipData**

```
 if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                    ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                    ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                        ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                        Uri uri = item.getUri();
                        mArrayUri.add(uri);
                        Toast.makeText(this, "" + getImageFilePath(uri), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
```

For Image Path:

```
public String getImageFilePath(Uri uri) {

        File file = new File(uri.getPath());
        String[] filePath = file.getPath().split(":");
        String image_id = filePath[filePath.length - 1];

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{image_id}, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));

            cursor.close();
            return imagePath;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: The method getImageFilePath(Uri uri) works like charm